# PHP bind object fields from result set

Tags: php, sql, oop, resultset

I have the following PHP class:

```
class Dog  
{  
   var $name;  
   var $age;  
   var $gender;
}
```

I have the following sql statement:

```
$sql = 'Select NAME,VALUE from dog_Details where id = 1';  
$results = $this->db->query($sql);  
$dog = new Dog();
foreach($results as $result)  
{  
  $dog->$result->NAME = $result->VALUE;  //This fails
}
```

PHP error:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Question:
How do I bind values dynamically from the result set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
$dog->{$result->NAME} = $result->VALUE;
```

### EDIT:

I guess your dataset is like this:

```
ID   NAME   VALUE
--   ----   -----  
 1   name    Rex
 1   age     2
 1   gender  M
```

This approach utilizes `variable-variable` - using the content of a variable as the *name* of the other variable.

In the `$dog->$result->NAME` line, PHP will first try to parse `->$result` as a `variable-variable`. Apparently PHP did cast `$result` (which is `stdClass`) to `string` and that's why you saw `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string` error.

Using `{$result->NAME}` notation lets PHP know the intended parsing order of `->`.

```
// when $result->NAME holds 'name'
$dog->{$result->NAME} = $result->VALUE;
// becomes $dog->name = $result->VALUE;
```

Comment: Good to know about the notation in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$dog->NAME` instead of  `$dog->$result->NAME`

Comment: this ends up giving me the following:  Dog Object( [name] => [age] => [gender] => [NAME] => Rex

Comment: A just saw the error in your code, to help you further with your functionality, you have to be more specific, how the result should look like, and how is it looking now.

Comment: it results in an error as I had called out in my code, can't be much more specific than that.